# Not declared in scope C++ [Arrays]

Tags: c++

I have a quick question. Trying to create a method to print out an array, however, the compiler is telling me that it isn't declared in the scope.

Here's my code:

```
int main() {
    int theArray[10] = {41, 23, 43, 12, 43, 23, 12, 41, 29, 102};
    printArray(theArray, 10);
}
```

Here's my printArray method:

```
void printArray(int arr[], int size) {
    int i;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
       std::cout <<" "<< arr[i];
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to declare the function before `main`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. Just make sure that necessary `includes` are exist. And the order of the methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printArray(int arr[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << arr[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int theArray[10] = { 41, 23, 43, 12, 43, 23, 12, 41, 29, 102 };
    printArray(theArray, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Or use `forward declaration`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printArray(int arr[], int size);

int main() {
    int theArray[10] = { 41, 23, 43, 12, 43, 23, 12, 41, 29, 102 };
    printArray(theArray, 10);
    return 0;
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << arr[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, you may write it in more C++ modern Style:

**1) Using templated function** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
template<std::size_t N> void printArray(std::array<int, N> x) {
    for (auto const& item:x){
        std::cout << " " << item << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array <int, 10> theArray{ { 41, 23, 43, 12, 43, 23, 12, 41, 29, 102 } };
    printArray<10>(theArray);
    return 0;
}
```

**2)The better by using iterators:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
template<typename Iterator> void printArray(Iterator beg, Iterator end) {
    for (auto it = beg; it != end; it = std::next(it)){
        std::cout << " " << *it << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array <int, 10> theArray{ { 41, 23, 43, 12, 43, 23, 12, 41, 29, 102 } };
    printArray(std::begin(theArray), std::end(theArray));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Go with option 1. The forward declare doesn't get you anything here except another line of code to be maintained and weird linker errors if you change the function's prototype and not the forward declaration.

Comment: Or use a `std::vector` i know the memory storage is different, but will likely be more useful thing to learn in this scenario.

Comment: use std::vector just when the number of elements is not constant.